# Entity Framework Core - unwanted delete cascade

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have Entity Framework Core which performs additional delete which I don't want.

Model definition: I have two entities `Template` and `TemplateVersion`. A `TemplateVersion` are just next versions of template, so `TemplateVersion` has one `Template` (N:1 relation)

```
public class Template 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class TemplateVersion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Template Template { get;set; }
}
```

And up to now all is clear an working good.

**BUT**: I want to have information on `Template` level which is the current version of `TemplateVersion`, so my `Template` definition now looks like (`TemplateVersion` is the same as before)

```
public class Template 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TemplateVersion CurrentVersion { get; set;}
}
```

So what I want to have is `N` instances of `TemplateVersion` to point to `1` instance of `Template` but in the same time `Template` is pointing to `1` `TemplateVersion`

And here the magic starts: when I add one `Template` and one `TemplateVersion` all is working good.

```
Template ---- TemplateVersionPrevious.Template == Template
```

But when I add another instance of `TemplateVersion` pointing to the same `Template` (and update `Template`'s `CurrentVersion`) suddenly first instance of `TemplateVersion` has its `Template` field nulled.

```
Template ---- TemplateVersionPrevious.Template == null
         ---- TemplateVersionCurrent.Template == Template
```

I believe that it's because Entity Framework is thinking that I have a classic `1:1` relation and only one instance of `TemplateVersion` can have relation to the same `Template` - and it's because of `CurrentTemplate` field.

How can I tell Entity Framework that it should not clear my `TemplateVersion` relation?

Additional info: once I define my `TemplateVersion` entity as follows

```
public class TemplateVersion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(TemplateId))]
    public Template Template { get;set; }
    public int TemplateId {get;set;}
}
```

it's get even more interesting: previous instance of `TemplateVersion` is just deleted!

```
Template ---- TemplateVersionCurrent.Template == Template
```

Comment: Use fluent API to configure **two** relationships that you need. With data annotations and your current navigation properties EF always assumes single relationship.

Comment: @IvanStoev can you show how such configuration would look like?

Comment: an easy way to do it would be using modelBuilder.Entity<Template>().HasRequired(x=>x.CurrentVersion).WithMany(); this configures the model to not use the inverse navigation property for the same relationship. If you expose foreign keys, be careful to map those accordingly.

Comment: in TemplateVersion declare Template as virtual

Comment: @bilpor that does not helped

Comment: At the moment your classes show a circular reference. If you are looking for a 1:N relationship, then template Version doesn't need to reference template. if you need a N:N relationship then you probably require an intermediary class (much as you would tables in a RDBMS).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EF default conventions don't play well with multiple relationships between 2 entities. And data annotations don't play well with one-to-one relationships or unidirectional associations (relationships without navigation property at one of the ends).

You need to explicitly configure the desired relationships with fluent API. Since fluent API have different overloads for having/not having navigation property and it's important to use to correct overload, let say your model is exactly like this (by exactly I mean the navigation and explicit FK properties which affect the relationships, other properties are irrelevant):

```
public class Template 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TemplateVersion CurrentVersion { get; set; }
}

public class TemplateVersion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Template Template { get; set; }
}
```

the fluent configuration of the desired two relationships is as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Template>()
    .HasMany<TemplateVersion>()
    .WithOne(e => e.Template)
    .IsRequired();

modelBuilder.Entity<Template>()
    .HasOne(e => e.CurrentVersion)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Template>("TemplateVersionId")
    .IsRequired(false);
```

Note that you have defined circular relationship, hence one of them should be optional. I've choosen `Template..TemplateVersionId` to be the optional wich sounds logical to me.

Also note that for one-to-one relationships, the principal and dependent ends cannot be uniquely determined from `HasOne`/ `WithOne`, so you need to use `HasForeignKey` and `HasPrinciplaKey` **generic type argument** to specify that (in contrast, one-to-many relationships have no such issue because the one side is always the principal and manu side is the dependent).

For more info, see [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships).